# Trouble passing data from ActionLink to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I am brand new to MVC and I am trying to pass data from actionlink in my view to the controller.

My controller looks like,

```
public ActionResult BookGenre(string id)
```

I am trying to pass a string id from my view.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Book", "GenreBook", "Book", new {id = sport}, null)
```

Everything I found on Google I could not get to work. Thanks

Comment: How are your Routes setup in Global.asax? Also is your BookGenre Action inside a BookController?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the actionlink to point to "BookGenre" and not "GenreBook". Also, you need to put speech-marks around the id sport. Your actionlink should look like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Book", "BookGenre", new {id = "sport"}, null)
```

Comment: Thanks it is not giving me an error message now but it is passing a null value.

Comment: You don't really need the last parameter of null either so your ActionLink can be set-up like this: `@Html.ActionLink("Book", "BookGenre", new {id = "sport"})`.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is very finicky about parameter types. Are you sure the BookGenre id should be a string?

Comment: Yeah I am pretty sure it needs to be a string.